# Why doesn't my effector work like I want it to with the new Mantaflow (Blender 2.82)?

Tags: animation, physics, fluid-simulation, collision

I want the plane highlighted in the picture to work as kind of a surface for the water simulation to run through, but when I go ahead and simulate it, it just goes through the object like if it was not there. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found out was was the problem, the normals were in the wrong direction. Once I flipped them, it worked like a charm.